# Simple_form :remember_me checkbox in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a `:remember_me` checkbox in the login form on my website. After writing the following code for the checkbox, it appears as a text input, not a checkbox. How would I turn this into a checkbox?

```
<%= simple_form_for :session, url: login_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Email Address", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, inline_label: "Remember me", class: "checkbox inline" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "log in", class: "btn btn-success btn-block login-bar" %>
<% end %>
```

In my `User.rb` file I have the following methods:

```
def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end

def forget
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end
```

Comment: Everything worked fine when It wasn't used in a `simple_form`, So I'm pretty sure it was (unless using this gem is altering something I don't know).

Comment: I've tried this out. The checkbox is centered in the text field and is the same height as it. It also highlights the border of the text field when I select the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple_form provides a `boolean` helper ([source](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type))
So you just have to do :

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, inline_label: "Remember me", class: "checkbox inline" %>
```

(assuming `remember_me` returns a boolean attribute)